# ruby lambda context

Tags: ruby, lambda, metaprogramming

Lets say I have the following ruby definition at the topmost level

```
callable = lambda {"#{hi}"}
```

and suppose that later on I create an object called `temp` that has a method called `hi`. Now what I would like to do is call `callable` within the context of `temp`. I have tried doing

```
temp.instance_eval do callable.call end
```

but this gives me the error "`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'hi' for main:Object`". I would like to know if there is any way to rebind the context of `callable` to `temp` so that I don't get an error message? I know that I could define `method_missing` on main:Object and reroute all method calls to `temp` but this seems like way too big of a hack to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the code you are looking for is

```
temp.instance_eval(&callable)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the difference between `temp.instance_eval(&callable)` and `temp.instance_eval do callable.call end`. It seems to me that either one should work but the latter doesn't for some reason.

Comment: @davidk01: b/c a Proc normally uses the context in which it is defined.  instance_eval forces the given proc to use the context of the calling object, but doesn't do so recursively (so procs called w/in that proc are not context-shifted).

Comment: @rampion: what you said doesn't make sense because `&callable` is also a proc and it does get context-shifted and it actually works properly when we use `instance_eval(&callable)`

Comment: @davidk01: Right.  `&callable` is the given proc in that case, so it *is* context shifted.  `meth(&(lambda { whatever }))` and `meth { whatever }` are equivalent.  `meth { lambda { whatever }.call }` is not necessarily equivalent to the other two.

Comment: @rampion: So what you're saying is that `obj.instance_eval(&callable) != obj.instance_eval {callable.call}` even though in both instances `self` is shifted to `obj`. Incidentally is this a bug or a deliberate implementation choice because my understanding is that `&callable == do callable.call end`

Comment: @rampion: Ha, I just got it. Thanks for the explanation it took me a while to figure out what you meant by

>but doesn't do so recursively

Comment: I would explain it as the & being very similar to the * syntax on lists of arguments. The ampersand is sort-of unpacking the proc back into a pure unbound block. (This probaby isn't actually what happens, but behavior-wise this is accurate enough).