# when calling instance_eval(&lambda) to pass current context got error 'wrong number of arguments'

Tags: ruby, lambda, metaprogramming

To be clear - this code is running perfectly - [code with proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470508/ruby-lambda-context)

but if instead I change Proc.new to lambda, I'm getting an error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

May be this is because instance_eval wants to pass self as a param, and lambda treats as a method and do not accept unknown params?

There is two examples - first is working:

```
class Rule
  def get_rule
    Proc.new { puts name }
  end
end

class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def init_rule 
    @name = "ruby"
    instance_eval(&Rule.new.get_rule)
  end
end
```

second is not:

```
class Rule
  def get_rule
    lambda { puts name }
  end
end

class Person
   attr_accessor :name

   def init_rule 
     @name = "ruby"
     instance_eval(&Rule.new.get_rule)
   end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually correct in your assumption.  Self is being passed to the `Proc` and to the lambda as it is being `instance_eval`'ed.  A major difference between Procs and lambdas is that lambdas check the arity of the block being being passed to them.

So:

```
 class Rule
   def get_rule
     lambda { |s| puts s.inspect; puts name; }
   end
 end


class Person
   attr_accessor :name

   def init_rule 
     @name = "ruby"
     instance_eval(&Rule.new.get_rule)
   end
end

 p = Person.new
 p.init_rule

 #<Person:0x007fd1099f53d0 @name="ruby">
 ruby
```

Here I told the lambda to expect a block with arity 1 and as you see in the argument inspection, the argument is indeed the `self` instance of Person class.

Comment: Isn't it `p.get_rule` instead of `p.init_rule`?

Comment: No it isn't. The code originally posted is calling instance_eval when calling `Person#init_rule` which is what I called and got that input, and the subject of the question. Editing my answer back to what it was.