# Random trait with FactoryBot

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I would like to use FactoryBot to return trait randomly like that:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do

    [:active, inactive].sample

    trait :active do
      active { true }
      ...
    end
    trait :inactive do
      active { false }
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

To do that:

```
(1..5).map{ |e| FactoryBot.build(:user) }.map(&:active?)
=> [true, false, false, true, false]
```

Actually is like that:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    active                    { [true, false].Sample }
    name                      { "name-#{SecureRandom.uuid}" }
    birthday                  { active == true ? rand(18..99).years.ago - rand(0..365).days.ago : nil }
    preferred_contact_method  { active == true ? %w(phone email).sample : nil }
    activated_at              { active == true ? rand(1..200).days.ago : nil }
    contact_phone_number      { preferred_contact_method == "phone" ? "+33XXXXXXXXX" : nil }
    contact_email             { preferred_contact_method == "email" ? "toto@tati.com" : nil }
  end
end
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to write: `FactoryBot.build(:user, [:active, :inactive].sample)`?

Comment: It works but you have to think about it every time you use the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Working on an eventual answer, I came across the fact that a `trait` execute only once the block it is given. I'll share the sample of code I was on for the time being, although if you test it, you will only have active users or inactive users, but not both.

---

You could export the logic of your traits in two lambdas and then choose one by random:

```
trait_active = lambda do |context|
    context.active { true }
    #...
end
trait_inactive = lambda do |context|
    context.active { false }
    # ...
end

FactoryBot.define do
    factory :user do
        trait :active do
            trait_active.call(self)
        end
        trait :inactive do
            trait_inactive.call(self)
        end
        trait :schrodinger do
            [trait_active, trait_inactive].sample.call(self)
        end
    end
end
```

The `context` attribute in the lambda is quite important here, you can see more
about that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730767/6320039).

Answer (score 0):

That is quite an old question, but just had the same need as OP and I think I found the solution, alas it is not pretty:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    active { nil }

    initialize_with do
      if active.nil?
        build :user, %i[active inactive].sample, attributes
      else
        User.new(attributes)
      end
    end
    
    trait :active do
      active { true }
      ...
    end
    trait :inactive do
      active { false }
      ...
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.create_list(:user, 5).map(&:active) #=> random array of booleans
FactoryBot.create_list(:user, 5, :active).all?(&:active?) #=> true
```